# Search suggestion places search word infront of suggestions

Tags: ajax, wordpress, search

Currently, I am working on a project I've "inherited" from someone else and have trouble fixing some stuff.

Just when I thought I am done with this project, I found, that if I search for example "apple" and the suggestions of the search are "foo apple bar", it will throw out "apple foo  bar"

Here is the code:

```
function select_data()
{
global $wpdb;
$product_name=$_POST['product_name'];

if(!empty($product_name))
{
$unique_id = 'prodct_search';
$query ="SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_title` LIKE '%".$product_name."%' AND `post_type` = 'product'";

$locar = $wpdb->get_results($query);

if($locar)
{
echo '<ul>';
foreach($locar as $loca)
{
echo '<li id="'.$loca->ID.'" onClick="filladsearch_loc('.this.',\''.addslashes($loca->post_title).'\',\''.$unique_id.'\')">'.$loca->post_title.'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
}
else
{
  echo '<ul><li>No products were found matching your search.</li></ul>';
}
}
die();
}
```

And

```
function select_data1()
{
global $wpdb;
$product_name=$_POST['product_name'];

if(!empty($product_name))
{
$unique_id = 'prodct_search';
$query ="SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_title` LIKE '%".$product_name."%' AND `post_type` = 'product'";

$locar = $wpdb->get_results($query);

if($locar)
{
echo '<ul>';
foreach($locar as $loca)
{
    $titcapital=strtoupper($loca->post_title);
    $proupper=strtoupper($product_name);
    $stringsearched=str_replace($proupper,"",$titcapital);
    //$createdarr=explode($product_name,$loca->post_title);
    $finalstring='<span class="pro_top">'.strtoupper($product_name).'</span>'.strtoupper($stringsearched);
    //print_r($createdarr);

echo '<li id="'.$loca->ID.'" onClick="filladsearch_loc('.this.',\''.addslashes($titcapital).'\',\''.$unique_id.'\')">'.$finalstring.'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
}
else
{
  echo '<ul><li>No products were found matching your search.</li></ul>';
}
}
die();
}
```

And here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Check your .pro_top CSS class. May be it has float:left setting. If any trouble, write your URL here

Comment: That was my idea, too, but it only has a colour. What I think is, that the code somehow strips out the keyword from the result and puts it in front.

Comment: without checking live URL it is difficult to say more